# Operators as method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, ruby, lambda, extension-methods

I don't think it's possible to use operators as a parameters to methods in C# 3.0 but is there a way to emulate that or some syntactic sugar that makes it seem like that's what's going on?

I ask because I recently implemented [the thrush combinator in C#](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/10/06/the-thrush-combinator-in-c) but while translating [Raganwald's Ruby example](http://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2008-10-30/thrush.markdown#readme)

```
(1..100).select(&:odd?).inject(&:+).into { |x| x * x }
```

> Which reads "Take the numbers from 1 to 100, keep the odd ones, take the sum of those, and then answer the square of that number."

I fell short on the [Symbol#to_proc](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/11/fun-with-symboltoproc.html) stuff. That's the &: in the `select(&:odd?)` and the `inject(&:+)` above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in simple terms you can just use a lambda:

```
public void DoSomething(Func<int, int, int> op)
{
    Console.WriteLine(op(5, 2));
}

DoSomething((x, y) => x + y);
DoSomething((x, y) => x * y);
// etc
```

That's not very exciting though. It would be nice to have all those delegates prebuilt for us. Of course you could do this with a static class:

```
public static class Operator<T>
{
     public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Plus;
     public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Minus;
     // etc

     static Operator()
     {
         // Build the delegates using expression trees, probably
     }
}
```

Indeed, Marc Gravell has [done something very similar](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), if you want to look. You could then call:

```
DoSomething(Operator<int>.Plus);
```

It's not exactly pretty, but it's the closest that's supported at the moment, I believe.

I'm afraid I really don't understand the Ruby stuff, so I can't comment on that...

Comment: Excellent answer, the Operator class seems to be pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Will have try it out later though.

Answer (score 2):

The following is direct, literal (as much as possible) C# translation:

```
(Func<int>)(x => x * x)(
    Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 1)
        .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y))
```

Specifically:

- blocks: `{||}` - become lambdas: `=>`
- `select` becomes `Where`
- `inject` becomes `Aggregate`
- `into` becomes a direct call on a lambda instance

Comment: Very nice except it misses the point of the Thrush combinator which in this case is to move the x*x to the end for readability. Worth a +1 anyway.

Comment: Didn't realise that to be the case - I just looked at Scala translation, which does the same thing I did. That said, `.Into()` could be trivially written as an extension method if wanted.

Comment: Ghosh's Scala implementation is very nice:

(1 to 100)

  .filter(_ % 2 != 0)

  .foldLeft(0)(_ + _)

  .into((x: Int) => x * x)

Comment: Yup, placeholders simplify things a bit. Actually, come to think of it, C# has operator overloading, so I think it would be possible to define `_` and overload operators for it in such a way that it would produce lambdas... it wouldn't let you write `_.foo()` like Scala does, but it would let you write `_ + 1` or even `_ + _`. I'll need to think about it.