# programmatically specify operator

Tags: c#, operators

Is it possible to specify an operator `R` where `R` can be an arithmetic, relational or logical operator ?

For example a function that calculates

```
c = a R b
```

where I can specify whether `R` is `+, -, *, /`

Can this be done in C# ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the most-generic way to do so means learning about [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). :) How will the operator to be used be determined?

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528319/operators-as-method-parameters-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [binary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) is any function which accepts two operands. It is simple to abstract this functionality using [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which are basically wrappers around methods (functions).

To make this clearer, we can define a generic method which does nothing more that invoke the delegate using specified parameters, and return its result:

```
public Tout GetResult<TIn, TOut>(TIn a, TIn b, Func<TIn, TIn, TOut> @operator)
{
     return @operator(a, b);
}
```

And you could use it to pass any combination of parameters and operators:

```
private bool AreEqual(int a, int b)
{
     return a.Equals(b);
}

private int Subtract(int a, int b)
{
     return a - b;
}
```

You can then use the same generic method to do whatever operation you want:

```
// use the "AreEqual" operator
bool equal = GetResult(10, 10, AreEqual);

// use the "Subtract" operator
int difference = GetResult(10, 10, Subtract);
```

Using lambda expressions, you can even create the operator "on the fly", by specifying it as an anonymous method:

```
// define a "Product" operator as an anonymous method
int product = GetResult(10, 10, (a,b) => a*b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something very close to that using lambda:

```
Func<int, int, int> op = (x, y) => x + y; // or any other operator
```

And then use it like any other delegate:

```
int result = op(1, 2);
```

If the type in question were user-defined with overloaded operators, you could use reflection, but I'm afraid it's not possible for types like `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Expression Trees - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score -3):

It is possible to have operator overloading in C#, check some MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It doesn't sound like the OP wants to change the functionality of a given operator - it sounds like, given two operands, they want to pick the operation at runtime.

Comment: he's asking to specify the operator, not overload its behavior in a class/struct

Comment: I think this is a good answer; it can be used to get the desired functionality.